# Gmail contextual gadget won't show up to domain admin

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I've an app on the google apps marketplace and has this strange issue.
The contextual gadget works fine for every user but the one who installed the app.
I've tested on 3 different domains and have the same result, I've also waited about 2 weeks but nothing changes.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more? so the person who installed the app in a domain cannot use the contextual gadget but it works for everyone in the domain?

Comment: That's right, the gadget doesn't even shows up for the admin (the one who installed the app) but it's ok for the other users. Any thoughts?